# Tomcat Log is showing wrong date

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm, log4j, tomcat8

Today, it is February 14th. However, in Tomcat logs, it is showing 45-Feb-2020.

At school, I learnt there can be at most 31 days in a month.

Please share if you have any idea on this.

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Check the log output format in your application (should be in the resources folder if you are indeed using a spring-boot app) - it seems that you are incorrectly setting the date format (i.e. printing the Nth day of the year instead of the Nth day of the month)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you configured day in a year instead of a day in a month. See your log4j configuration and change `%d{DD-MM-yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss.SSS}` by `%d{dd-MM-yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss.SSS}`. Pay attention to the uppercased *DD* and lowercased *dd*